# Cadena Palíndroma MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Esto intentado hacer una funcion para comparar si un texto es Palíndromo o no, es decir si se le igual de izquierda a derecha que de derecha a izquierda. Estoy utilizando el comando reverse de manera erronea ya que lo que hace es darle la vuelta al texto por lo que siempre se va a leer igual, pero no se cual utilizar para ello. Dejo por aqui mi codigo actual.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CADENACAPICUA;

DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION CADENACAPICUA(cadena TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT

BEGIN
     DECLARE cadena TEXT;
     DECLARE mensaje TEXT;
 CASE
      WHEN cadena = REVERSE (cadena)
      THEN SET mensaje = ' Este texto es Capicua'; 
      ELSE SET mensaje = 'Este texto NO es capicua'; 
      END CASE;

 RETURN(mensaje);

END |

DELIMITER ;

SELECT CADENACAPICUA('PACO') AS 'RESULTADO CADENACAPICUA';
```

Comment: Solo a manera de utilizar los terminos de forma correcta, el termino capicua se utiliza solo para numeros que se leen de la misma forma en ambos sentidos, para el caso de palabras se utiliza el termino palindromo, es decir, en tu funcion estas evaluando palabras o cadenas palindromas no capicua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así y te funcionará:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CADENACAPICUA;

DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION CADENACAPICUA(cadena TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT

BEGIN
     DECLARE mensaje TEXT;
     SET cadena=REPLACE(cadena,' ','');
     CASE
     WHEN cadena = REVERSE (cadena)
     THEN SET mensaje = ' Este texto es Capicua'; 
     ELSE SET mensaje = 'Este texto NO es capicua'; 
     END CASE;
     RETURN(mensaje);
END |

DELIMITER ;

SELECT CADENACAPICUA('PACO') AS 'RESULTADO CADENACAPICUA';
SELECT CADENACAPICUA('ANA') AS 'RESULTADO CADENACAPICUA';
```

No es necesario el `DECLARE cadena TEXT;` porque declaras esa variable al definir la función.

Comment: Perfecto, si funciona, Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Creo que sería importante eliminar espacios, los cuales no son considerados para los palíndromos.

Comment: Ok @LuisCazares, respuesta modificada eliminando espacios